# What is the square bracketed field in the interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
export interface Principal {
  name: string; // just a field
  [attribute: string]: any; // allowed custom fields

  [securityId]: string; // what does this mean ?
}
```

What does securityId mean ?

Answer (score 6):

`securityId` is a computed property name.

To make this code compile, `securityId` must be a value with type constrained to a literal string, or a unique symbol type.

For example:

```
const securityId: "security" = "security";

interface Principal {
    [securityId]: string;
}
```

specifies a property named `security`.

If `securityId` doesn't have a literal type, this will be an error:

```
const securityId: string = "security";

interface Principal {
    // ERROR: A computed property name in an interface must refer to an
    // expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
    [securityId]: string;
}
```

Note: I've tried to find references to this behavior in the specification but it appears out of date and [not a priority](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15711) - edits welcome!

Comment: This is almost entirely correct but, as indicated by the compiler message, computed property keys may also be unique symbols, not just string literals. In fact, this is the only way to specify a symbol keyed property.

Comment: Also updated @Aluan Haddad, but I'm not sure how to create one - feel free to add examples

Comment: Thank you. I don't think you need to add an example, I just wanted to correct that language. Plus one. To create a unique symbol, just write `Symbol()`.

Answer (score 1):

`securityId` is called a [constant-named property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#constant-named-properties) on a type, introduced in TypeScript v2.7:

```
const securityId = Symbol() // create symbol value

export interface Principal {
  [securityId]: string; // .. and use it as property name in the *type system*
}
```

You can also use a `number` or `string` instead of [`Symbol`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html) - be aware, that all need to  be `const` variables:

```
// works
const securityId = 3 // number literal type
const securityId = "foo" // string literal type

// doesn't work
let securityId = "foo" // let
const securityId: string = "foo" // wide string
```

Constant-named properties are the equivalent of [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) in the type system and especially useful in  combination with [well-known symbols](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html#well-known-symbols) or unique user properties like with [branded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal).

[Here is a code example on the Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmwCuAnAllAngSQCYwF4YBlTAWwCMQAbACgEoYB6JmYFeAQynjnKuowAbp2pJ4AKAksYAdxAoA1hGmtQkWAmToseQjADMzVmCSV4KGNQwXRMLAAdJM9dDiJUGHPiIAiAGYgIL7GcFDoYADmVjYodo6SqjC4IPAQYADksPJKSdTwmh463voBQSEyKWmZ2QqKSa6F2l54AFxhEdF+gcEwUhLwAB4OCrBoYDwo-pzAvAAKEcBoDnYA3hIwMADaWp66uAC67dCdANyhAHQXMJxg+EgIMBg3EDAOKCBOKFgwYJxkvHG9gAFrwAFQJPjQeBkMESAC+EiAA)